# How do I split a list of emails with multiple formats in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, email, split

I have a list of emails and the email have two formats:

1. with name `name <email@address.com>`
2. without name `email@address.com`

I am wondering if there is a way to split this list with different separators in Javascript.

List of examples :
`email@address.com,name1 <email1@address.com>,email2@address.com`
or
`email@address.com,email1@address.com,email2@address.com`
or
`email@address.com email1@address.com name2 <email2@address.com>`
or
`email@address.com email1@address.com email2@address.com`
or

```
email@address.com
name1 <email1@address.com>
email2@address.com
```

or

```
email@address.com
email1@address.com
email2@address.com
```

For the moment I split the list with the three separators for the simple email format `email@address.com` and I still confused with how to do it including the name format `name <email@address.com>`?

Here is the code I used for that:

```js
    var emailInput = $(this);
    var clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    var pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
    var emails = pastedData.split(/[\r,\s]+/);
```

What I need to extract for example 
`email@adress.com name <email@address.com>` 
==> `["email@address.com","name <email@address.com>"]`

Comment: Maybe `pastedData.match(/[^\s<>,@]+@[^\s<>,]+/g)` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't work for the split method `var emails = pastedData.split(/[^\s<>,@]+@[^\s<>,]+/g);`

Comment: You do not need to use `split`, do you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I need to split the list to get each email alone

Comment: No, you do not. You can always extract data using the method that work best in the current scenario.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh you are right it works to get this `email@address.com` ! 
But what if I want to get this format `name <email@address.com>` or this one `email@address.com`

Comment: I don't understand your concern, the regex solution [matches all emails in your post](https://regex101.com/r/Mcn9uV/2).

Comment: I need to extract for example
`email@adress.com name <email@address.com>`
==> `["email@address.com","name <email@address.com>"]`

Comment: Try `pastedData.split(/(?<![\S<])\s*([^\s<>,@]+@[^\s<>,]+)\s*/)`

Comment: No it doesn't work for all cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not looking for an *email address validator*, and already know that your list has email addresses, then you can do:

```js
let data = `
email1@address.com,name2 <email2@address.com>,email3@address.com
email4@address.com,email5@address.com,email6@address.com
email7@address.com email8@address.com name9 <email9@address.com>
email10@address.com email11@address.com email12@address.com
name13 <email13@address.com>
email14@address.com
email15@address.com
email16@address.com
`;

let result = data.match(/[^,;<>\s]+@[^,;<>\s]+|[^,;<>\s]+\s+<[^,;<>\s]+@[^,;<>\s]+>/g);

console.log(result);
```